# Find all generalized eigenvectors of T.

Tags: linear-algebra

Define $T \in L(C^2)$ by $T(w, z) = (z, 0)$.

Find all generalized eigenvectors of T.

What I tried:

$ \lambda w = z$

$ \lambda z = 0$.

So to me it looks like $\lambda = 0$ is an eigenvalue when $z = 0$??

I'm kind of confused on this problem can anyone help?

Comment: What does $T(w, z)$ mean in terms of $\Bbb C^4$ and $L(\Bbb C^4)$?  are $w, z \in \Bbb C^2$ in some sense?

Comment: Furthermore, what exactly is meant by "generalized" eigenvector in this context?

Comment: Yes $w, z \in C^4$ and generalized eigenvector would mean a general form of all the eigenvectors. So if $lambda = 0$ was an eigenvector when $z = 0$ then the general eigenvector would look like $(w, 0)$ for all $w \in C^4$.

Comment: If $w, z \in \Bbb C^4$, how do I interpret $T(w, z)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your matrix in the canonical basis (supposed you are working on $\mathbb{C}^2$) is
$$\left( \begin{array}{cc}
0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 \end{array}\right)$$
It is already a Jordan block so the eigenvalue is only $\lambda=0$ and the eigenvectors are the elements of the canonical basis, $e_1,e_2$.

A generalized eigenvector with eigenvalue $\lambda$ is an element of the null space of the matrix $(A-I\lambda)^k$ for some $k\in\mathbb{N}$.

Errata: for it to be a generalized eigenvector it must not be in $\text{ker}(A-I\lambda)^{k-1}$.

$\lambda w=z$

$\lambda z=0$

means that $\lambda=0$ and $z=0$ but this will only give you the standard eigenvectors.

Comment: Sorry to bother you so many months on, but would it be fair to say that all vectors in $\mathbb{C}^2$ are generalized eigenvectors of $T$ since $T^2=0$?

Comment: There is an imprecision in my answer: A generalized eigenvector with eigenvalue $\lambda$ of a linear application $T$ is an element of $\text{ker}(T-I\lambda)^k$ which is not in $\text{ker}(T-I\lambda)^{k-1}$. So the answer is no.

Comment: Axler's "Done Right" seems to disagree, but it may be a matter of convention. Thank you for your response. I'll note both.